# Graceful process shutdown on Android

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I terminate an app in the Android Emulator so that Activity's onDestroy is called? Stopping the process from the Devices window seems to be a process kill, not a graceful closing like the OS does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pressing the back button in the emulator should finish the activity and call onDestroy. That I suppose is the default behavior if you have not overridden it through onBackPressed.

Comment: Does not terminate the process, but kills the activity. Good for my purposes.

Comment: Yep. Android takes care of terminating the process. Huge discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238